# Product Chain Power Rule： Either it's the book or I am wrong.

Tags: derivatives

The problem:　$x^3\sqrt{2x+4}$

$f(x):= x^3$,  $g(x):= \sqrt{2x+4}$

$(f\times g)' = f^{\prime}g+fg^{\prime}$  thus it should be

$3x^2\sqrt{2x+4} + (x^3)[\frac{1}{2}(2x+4)^{\frac{-1}{2}}(2)]$

which is $3x^2\sqrt{2x+4}+\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{2x+4}}$

The book gives: $3x^2\sqrt{2x+4}+\frac{x^3}{2\sqrt{2x+4}}$

I'm correct? I always get worry when my answers don't match the book.

$\frac{d}{dx}[f\times g(h(x))] = f^{\prime} \times g(h(x))+ f\times g^{\prime}(h(x))h^{\prime}$ right?

Comment: Last formula should be $g'(h(x))h'$, not $g(h(x))'h'$.

Comment: Your answer to the problem is the correct one, I think. Books have typos. For simple derivatives such as this you can [check with a computer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+x%5E3+sqrt%282x+%2B+4%29), if you trust computers.

Comment: @DylanMoreland I really know that I am correct, its just that I panic when I don't have what the book says.

Comment: @Dylan You could write an answer so that OP will choose the answer and keep this away from those Unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my colleagues have astutely pointed out, the product rule states $(fg)^{\prime} = f^{\prime} g + f g^{\prime}$. Define $f(x)= x^3$ and $g(x)= \sqrt{2x+4}$. As $f^{\prime}(x) = 3 x^{2}$ and $g^{\prime}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x+4}}$,  the product rule gives
\begin{align}
(f(x)g(x))^{\prime} = f^{\prime}(x) g(x) + f(x) g^{\prime}(x) = 3x^{2} \sqrt{2x + 4} + \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{2x+4}}. 
\end{align}
The answer in your book has an incorrect factor of $2$ in the denominator of the second term. This factor should cancel with the factor of $2$ coming from $2x$ (in $g(x)$) by the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct and the best way to check that you are indeed correct and book is wrong is by using Wolfram Alpha,  check http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+x%5E3%5Csqrt%7B2x%2B4%7D  for instance, your answer can be verified by simplifying the expression.